# How to calculate intersection and normal at for a plane with ripples / waves

Tags: c#, math, raytracing

I'm fiddling with a ray tracer in C# and have various primitives working. However, I'd like to create water with ripples and I'm not sure how to create such a surface type.

Surfaces implement an abstract class which adds an intersection to a list and calculate the normal at the intersection.

Ideally I'd want a surface that's infinite in two axis (like the plane) but also takes a wave octave array to create waves or ripples.

Here's the current plane implementation:

```
    public class Plane : Surface
    {
        public override void AddIntersections(Ray ray, ref List<Intersection> intersections)
        {
            if (ray.Direction.Y.Near(0.0f))
                return;

            double distance = -ray.Position.Y / ray.Direction.Y;

            intersections.Add(new Intersection(this, distance));
        }
        public override Vector3 SurfaceNormaAt(Vector3 point, Intersection intersection)
        {
            return Directions.Up;
        }
    }
```

I've worked with creating waves and combining them, but the mathematical implementation for ray tracing eludes me.

EDIT: The Surface type includes a transformation matrix

Comment: There *might* be a parametric solution for a sinusoidal surface, but even if there is, a single frequency will likely not look good, and it might not be practical to evaluate. The typical approach is to take some high level description of the surface, and convert it to simpler primitives. This might be triangles, bezier patches, or voxels depending on your exact needs. Do note that intersection and normal calculation are not independent for surfaces. If you hit a triangle you need that triangle to compute the normal, just not the position the intersection was at.